# Derivative of a trace with respect to a scalar

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, trace

I have 3 given matrices $A,B$ and $C$ and an unknown scalar $\alpha$. I would like to find the derivative $\frac{\partial f(\alpha)}{\partial\alpha}$ of the following function:
$f(\alpha)=\mathrm{trace}\big((A-\alpha BC)^T(A-\alpha BC)\big)$.

When I derived I found that it should be the sum of all the entries in the matrix $-C^TB^T(A-\alpha BC)-(A-\alpha BC)^TBC$ but it doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: Why does it not look correct to you? You got the right answer.

Comment: because when I checked the gradient in matlab it says that is not correct.

Comment: It is not the sum of all the entries, but the trace of the matrix you wrote down, maybe that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : you can expand $(A-\alpha BC)^T(A-\alpha BC)$ and then you may see $f$ as a polynomial in $\alpha$ (don't forget that the trace is linear!).